# How to measure execution time of several functions in a loop in C

Tags: c, performance-testing

I hope to find a way to measure execution time of several functions in a for loop in C. For example, there is code like:

```
for(;;)
{
    func1();
    func2();
    func3();
}
```

I want to know how much time program spends totally on func1() (or func2, func3).

I know I can use clock() to measure time. However, in this case if I write the code like:

```
for(;;)
{
    a = clock();
    func1();
    b = clock();
    time_func1 += (b-a);
    a = clock();
    func2();
    b = clock();
    time_func2 += (b-a);
    a = clock();
    func3();
    b = clock();
    time_func3 += (b-a);
}
```

It looks like too stupid and the result is not accurate.

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Linux, I'd suggest you to use [`clock_gettime`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime). This enables precise time measurement with several clocks, also with high resolution. `clock` itself has a low resolution.

Maybe a word regarding its use:

```
timespec t1, t2;

clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &t1);
/* CODE TO BE MEASURED */
clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &t2);
```

Answer (score 1):

`clock()` has a very low resolution. Depending your OS, there are more accurate functions.

In Windows there's [QueryPerformanceCounters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

`clock()` will also give not the real execution time if multi-threaded code is present.

Answer (score 0):

Sebastian is right,

According to the man page, the POSIX function clock() returns an approximation of the clock ticks (what do they mean by approximation ?) used by the program. You have to divide by the number of clocks per second to get the execution time.
This is done by:

```
int main() {
    clock_t start;
    clock_t end;
    double cpu_time_used;

    start = clock();
    # do some computations
    end = clock();

    cpu_time_used = ((double) (end-start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}
```

It is easy to use and you get the CPU ticks for the calling process, but the precision is in milliseconds.

If you need more precision, the POSIX function clock_gettime() precision is order of nanoseconds. You can specify to retrieve the system-wide, per-process or thread-specific  elapsed time. Here's an example:

```
int main() {    
    timespec start;
    timespec end;

    double cpu_time_used;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &start);
    # do some computations
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &end);

    cpu_time_used = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) / 1000000000.0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want measure the time and further want to optimize those function better to go with profiling tools like oprofile there you will get to know which function is taking how much time.with 'opannotate' you will get to know in better way